# What is the distinction between ALTER TABLE MODIFY and ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

It seems to me there are two types of commands that can add constraints to columns in an existing table.

One is "ALTER TABLE MODIFY" (described [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-alter-table-modify-column/)), another is "ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT" (described [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php#:%7E:text=The%20syntax%20for%20creating%20a%20unique%20constraint%20using%20an%20ALTER,table_name)).

What is the distinction?

I'm studying for Oracle's 1Z0-071 test, and it references the standards of the Oracle 12c database.

Edit: “ADD CONSTRAINT”, not “MAKE CONSTRAINT”, sorry for the typo

Comment: Well, ALTER TABLE ... MAKE CONSTRAINT won't work because it is invalid syntax.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look it up in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).  Beyond that I've got to wonder why you are studying for an exam on 12c when that version is already out of support . . .

Comment: Your second link does not have the word "MAKE" next to the word "CONSTRAINT" so I'm not sure how you are coming up with that syntax.  As Ed points out, it isn't valid, but if the syntax appeared somewhere on the page you reference, we could at least hope to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I’m sorry, I meant to write “ADD CONSTRAINT”, fixed the post

Comment: You can `modify` a column to be not null or unique, which are types of constraint, but to add a named constraint you'll need to use, well, `add constraint`. The documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html). I am not sure what the question is.